# Should the nodatacow mount option be used in btrfs in a database server? Does it disable bit corruption checksums?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

I am looking at implementing btrfs in raid 10 configuration for a database server and I am an confused about the nodatacow option.

According to https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas:

> Files with a lot of random writes can become heavily fragmented
>   (10000+ extents) causing trashing on HDDs and excessive multi-second
>   spikes of CPU load on systems with an SSD or large amount a RAM. On
>   servers and workstations this affects databases and virtual machine
>   images. The nodatacow mount option may be of use here, with associated
>   gotchas.

The documentation then states that **nodatacow** option is:

> Do not copy-on-write data for newly created files, existing files are
>   unaffected. This also turns off checksumming! IOW, nodatacow implies
>   nodatasum. datacow is used to ensure the user either has access to the
>   old version of a file, or to the newer version of the file. datacow
>   makes sure we never have partially updated files written to disk.
>   nodatacow gives slight performance boost by directly overwriting data
>   (like ext[234]), at the expense of potentially getting partially
>   updated files on system failures. Performance gain is usually < 5%
>   unless the workload is random writes to large database files, where
>   the difference can become very large. NOTE: switches off compression !

Does this mean that this option should be selected for disks in database servers AND this using this option will disable corruption checksums?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's generally a good idea for databases, and yes it does disable checksumming (for the same reason that it disables in-line compression, and will probably disable encryption too once that's implemented).

That said, it's generally a better idea to not mount the whole filesystem with it, and instead mark the directory in which the database files will be stored before they are created by running `chattr +C` on it.  That particular attribute has the same effect as the `nodatacow` mount option, but operates on a per-file basis, and is inherited from the directory a file is created in.